# Storing colour space as a variable for EmguCV

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm trying to offer my users the option to toggle whether the detection uses Bgr or Gray colour spaces for optimisation purposes.

I saw that the type of these options is refered to as a "struct" which has the namespace of:

```
Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray

or

Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray
```

This is my current detection code, as you can see it's currently just using the Gray option.

```
while (!found)
{
    timeTaken = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    window = new Image<Gray, byte>(WindowOperations.TakeScreenshot(focusWindow));

    using (var result = window.MatchTemplate(detect, TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed))
    {
        result.MinMax(out var minValues, out var maxValues, out var minLocations, out var maxLocations);

        if (!(maxValues[0] > watchmanData.Profile.SettingsProfile.AccuracyDecimal)) continue;

        found = true;
        timeTaken.Stop();
    }
}
```

Ideally I would like something such as this (if possible):

```
while (!found)
{
    timeTaken = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    colourSpace = userChoice;

    window = new Image<colourSpace, byte>(WindowOperations.TakeScreenshot(focusWindow));

    using (var result = window.MatchTemplate(detect, TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed))
    {
        result.MinMax(out var minValues, out var maxValues, out var minLocations, out var maxLocations);

        if (!(maxValues[0] > watchmanData.Profile.SettingsProfile.AccuracyDecimal)) continue;

        found = true;
        timeTaken.Stop();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that c# does not allow you to use variable type parameters the way you want to. But you can separate your code into a typed method like this:

```
        public void Process(bool useGray)
        {
            if (useGray)
            {
                DoStuff<Gray>(new Image<Gray, byte>(100, 100), new Image<Gray, byte>(10, 10));
            }
            else
            {
                DoStuff<Bgr>(new Image<Bgr, byte>(100, 100), new Image<Bgr, byte>(10, 10));
            }
        }

        public void DoStuff<TColor>(Image<TColor, byte> window, Image<TColor, byte> pattern)
            where TColor : struct, IColor
        {

            using (var result = window.MatchTemplate(pattern, TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed))
            {
                result.MinMax(out var minValues, out var maxValues, out var minLocations, out var maxLocations);

                //... evaluate matching
            }
        }
```